# What is meant by "no need to move sd card share the same disk with os"?

Tags: app2sd, android-11, redmi, miui-12.5

I am using Redmi 9, 4/64, Android 11, MIUI Global 12.5.3. I was trying to move apps from internal to sd. But there was no option, though i enabled it in developer settings. I tried some app and they either showed **move to sd not supported in this device** or **no need to move sd card share the same disk with os**. So, how this works? If i run out of internal storage eventually, next will my sd card be used to store apps? Is there any way to move to sd?

Comment: For historical reasons Android has a section called "sdcard" but it is actually on the same flash chip like the rest of your data. The real SD-card is "external SD-card". I would assume that the message means moving app data onto this "emulated" sdcard doe snot make sens as the app data would still be on the same partition as before.

Comment: @Robert From your comment, I assume, if I insert a 64gb sd card, my internal memory will work as if it is 64+64 gb?

Comment: Only if your device allows to format the sd-card as internal storage (some manufacturer disable it to sell phones with larger flash memory). Otherwise it will be just another directory which is early used by apps.

Comment: @Robert can i get app2sd feature by using custom rom?

Comment: Not sure. In my opinion app2sd is a technology from the Android 4.x/5.x era. I have not used it for years. Formatting an sd-card as internal/adoptable storage is much easier as long as the sd-card is fast and reliable. The best way of course is just buying a phone with sufficient flash memory. Internal flash is faster and usually more reliable.

Comment: @Robert there was no format as internal option. Just format. Any idea?